# How do I track down this error message "could not find upload server" in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have recently inherited an iOS project within our company. It is written in Objective-C and all of those who have previously worked on it are no longer in the company.

Anytime I use the Product -> Clean Build Folder or Product -> Build I get an error message pop up at the end of the build that says "could not find upload server".

I have searched the code and do not see this anywhere, I have went though the build settings and do not see this anywhere either, and I have went through the build phases and rules and just can't figure out where this message is coming from.

Does anyone have a clue what this error message means or where I could look to figure it out?

The app compiles and builds fine, but I'd like to resolve this issue.

We do have a report upload project within the app so I'm not sure if it's related to that or if Xcode is trying to upload the project to some type of build server somewhere on our network. From some digging around, I was able to learn we used to have a MacMini that did builds but it hasn't been used for years and is no longer online.

Where can I look to find this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue after searching through GitHub. It seems there was a PostBuild script on the Scheme file which I was not aware existed.